# Unable to access mongodb collection from robo3T, when db is created in diff (27020) port. (able to make connection to db but not to coll)

Tags: database, mongodb, pymongo, robo3t

[error_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D90B.png) [config_27017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzJah.png) [config_27020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3tYg.png)
I am trying to extract data from one db(running in port 27017) and storing the extracted data in another db(27020). for 1st db I have set auth but not for 2nd db.
I have mongodb installed in aws instance. And I am Creating each database in different ports(i.e. 27017, 27020). Created separate mongo_config file for each port. Able to access newly created db from robo3T, However **accessing collection gives below error:**

```
**Error "ListCollection failed: {ok: 0.0, errmsg: "not authorized on <db> to execute command {listCollection:1, filter: {}, cursor: {}, $readPreference: {mode: "secondaryPreferred"}. $d..". code:13, codeName: "Unauthorized"}"}**
```

**Please suggest me the steps to create 2 mongo instances, listening to 2 diff ports in one server.**

Comment: The error is quite obvious. How do you connect? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: mongod --config /etc/mongod_two.conf

mongo --port 27020

>show dbs 

is not showing any db.

I did not create any user on mongodb running in 27020 port. but I do create user for admin db, when mongodb is running in 27017 port.

Comment: Why do you specify port in command line when you have a config file? Can you post your two config files?

Comment: if i run without specifying port, it by default takes 27017 port and listing its db and coll.

I have added both the config file img link above as [config_27017, config_27020]. Pls suggest me how can I access the db and collection of mongo running in port 27020.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, provide code and config file as formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: When you specify the port in config file, then you don't need `--port 27020` in command line.

Comment: In config file you enabled authentication on both, i.e. the only permitted (or at least the only useful) command is `createUser()`. Either create a user or disable authentication.

Comment: thanks for your continuous help @Wernfried Domscheit
. After removing the auth from both the files, I am able to create the collection from mongo shell running in aws localhost. However not able to connect to mongodb 27020, when I am connecting from remote server or robo3T using cmd:

Comment: $ mongo mongodb://<public_ip>:27020
MongoDB shell version v5.0.3
connecting to: mongodb://<public_ip>:27020/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server <public_ip>:27020, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to <public_ip>:27020 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1

Comment: inbound rules:
IPv4 Custom TCP TCP 27020 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Did you check the mongod logfile?